Completion of the Brownian motion filtration: is this right-continuous?
I am self-studying Durrett's probability book.
Let $\{B_t^x\}_{t \geq 0}$ be the Brownian motion starting from $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Here, the sample space is the set of continuous functions $\{ \omega| \omega:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous function} \}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the coordinate projection maps $\pi_t$. We have $B_t^x = \pi_t$, where $x$ indicates that the probability measure on this measurable space "starts from $x\in\mathbb{R}$".
Durrett constructs the following sigma-algebras on this measurable space.
$\mathcal{F}_t^0 = \sigma(\{\pi_s\}_{s \leq t})$ and
$\mathcal{F}_t^+ = \bigcap_{s>t}F_s^0$.
I am familiar with the properties of these $\sigma$-algebras (including the Blumenthal's 0-1 law).
Then, Durrett suggests the following constructions:
$\mathcal{F}_t^x = \sigma( F_t^+ \cup \{\text{all the $P_x$-null sets}\})$, where $P_x$ denotes the probability measure for the Brownian motion starting from $x$.
$\mathcal{F}_t = \bigcap_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \mathcal{F}_t^x$.
So basically, $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the completion of the right-continuous filtration $F_t^+$. I am curious if this is also right-continuous.
I am having difficulty proving/disproving this fact because this construction is slightly different from the standard completion of measure spaces.

Yes, it is still right-continuous.  First, note that $\mathcal F_{\cdot}^x$ is right-continuous for all $x$.  Now, suppose $A \in \mathcal F_s$ for all $s > t$.  Then $A \in \mathcal F_s^x$ for all $s > t$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathcal F_{\cdot}^x$ is right-continuous, this implies $A \in \mathcal F_t^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Hence, $A \in \bigcap_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathcal F_t^x = \mathcal F_t$ .  Since $t\ge 0$ was arbitrary, this shows $\mathcal F_{\cdot}$ is right-continuous.

If you are thinking of starting the Brownian motion in a random position then it's appropriate to work with
$$
\mathcal F_t^\mu:=\sigma(\mathcal F^o_t,\mathcal N^\mu)
$$
where $\mu$ is a probability measure on the Borel subsets of $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal N^\mu$ is the collection of $\Bbb P^\mu$-null sets in the $\Bbb P^\mu$ completion of $\mathcal F^o_\infty$. And then use $\cap_\mu \mathcal F^\mu_t$ for "completed filtration". Of course $\mathcal F^x_t$ is $\mathcal F^\mu_t$ when $\mu$ is the unit point mass at $x$.
It's worth noting that by Blumenthal's 0-1 law and the simple Markov property,  $\mathcal F_t^\mu$ is already right continuous.

Thank you, Dr. Dawkins. May I ask if $\bigcap_\mu \mathcal{F}^\mu_t = \bigcap_x \mathcal{F}^x_t$ holds? And, are these definitions ($\bigcap_\mu \mathcal{F}^\mu_t$ and/or $\bigcap_x \mathcal{F}^x_t$) common in the probability theory literature?
